# A end product user can't create an excel interop instance

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop, file-not-found

I'm creating a wpf application for internal deployment.

A user using the software is getting the following error when trying to create an excel interop instance.

`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID (...) failed due to the following error: 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified`

The section that is catching the error is the following

```
try
{
    _excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(_excelApplication.Hwnd, out ExcelAppProcessId);
    _excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //TODO Move message box to parents
    MessageBox.Show($"Termination Error: Could not open Excel Application: {e.Message}");

    Environment.Exit(110);
}
```

Previously the same user had an issue while trying to open Access (can't remember what the exact error was) and I implemented the following to fix it.

```
try
{
    //MessageBox.Show($"OS: {EnvironmentFunctions.is64BitOperatingSystem} Process: {EnvironmentFunctions.is64BitProcess}");

    if (EnvironmentFunctions.is64BitOperatingSystem && !EnvironmentFunctions.is64BitProcess)
    {
        string PathValue = "";
        string sAdd = "";
        string strCommonFiles =
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CommonProgramFiles(x86)");

        sAdd = ";" + strCommonFiles + "\\microsoft shared\\DAO";
        PathValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
        PathValue += sAdd;

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", PathValue);

    }

    _accessApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(_accessApplication.hWndAccessApp(), out AccessAppProcessId);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Termination Error: Could not open Access Application");
    Environment.Exit(110);
}
```

Would there be a similar solution but for the Excel interop?

Notes about the user: They are one of the few left running windows 7.

Comment: Office COM interop is dated and should no longer be used. It has all the usual issues of COM Interop. And a bunch of it's own, including but not limited to: 1. it needs a interactive session. Not a problem for Desktop applications, but a serious one (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services) for services and anything running as/in a service like Web Applications.
2. it needs office to be installed on the computer it is running. Because all it does is remoting a instance of office.

Comment: Only partially related, but Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and yours is bad. You catch exception - wich is way to wide - and only expose or log the message - if that much. Here are two articles I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Is "Office COM interop" the same thing as "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" (or subset of)? I'm pretty sure Office is installed on their computer (they open and use office applications) but I'll double check to make sure it isn't installed on a different directory then their local hard drive.

Comment: @Mandelbrotter Yes, "Microsoft.Office.Interop" is the Office COM Interop. | Regarding file not found: IIRC, with COM you have to register componenets, and a too modern version of Office might not have done this. | It could also be a rights issue. | There is plenty of reasons COM can fail, one of the big reasons we went over to .NET :)

Comment: Are you compiling for 64bit or 32? Have you tried building it as x86 by chance? I'm asking because if it's 32bit office it wont work with 64bit application.

Comment: 64bit. Previous issues were resolved by compiling to 64bit instead of [Any CPU].

Comment: Ok, try building it against x86...

Comment: If is is good old binarity missmatch, it is going to cause issues on either all the x32 or x64 Installations. One of the .NET Advantages is that it is bitness agnostic, after all. You need a longterm solution for this. I think people figured out workarounds for this (other then of course changing the library). Let me try to find it.

Comment: Found some of those old solutions: 1. Is to put the COM Interop calls into a helper process with fixed binarity, that your main process talks to via any IPC approach. (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/644c2f9c-f06a-496a-b497-6420a7919fdb/64-bit-app-calling-32-bit-dll) 2. Is making a wrapper around the DLL Imports (plural) (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/852544/NET-Interop-with-and-bit-DLLs). | Of course my advice is still to go over to OpenXML SDK, but I figure one of thoses "bosses" wants to use the old formats from some bossy reaason?

Comment: @Christopher thank you for those links, I'll be reading them shortly. I've been able to solve it by switching to 32bit but more information is always appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ switching everything to 32bit solved the issue. Could you post as answer for me to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID (...) failed due to the following error: 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified

Typically this error is caused by only a few issues, which I will list below.

1. Recent Windows updates
2. Partition issue's and or problems
3. Bitness issue's (determined what Office is installed on the end machine and what the application is compiled against)

I asked earlier about what you were targeting because you have some code that is checking if the pc is 64bit and you have already ran into some issues. This then lead me to bitness issues with creating instances of Excel.

***My recommendation and solution*** to your exact issue is because the end machine is 32bit, so compiling for x86/32bit should fix the issue.

On a final note, you may be able to remove that old code as it wouldn't be needed anymore.